# how to set email_required = false on signup with omniauth-twitter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth, twitter-oauth

In a Rails 3.2 app I'm using Devise on a User model, with omniauth-twitter. A User has many Authentications.

Login is via email + password, or via Twitter.

I'm trying to modify the email_required method so that email is not required if a User is signing up with Twitter (Twitter does not provide email in its email response). The User will then be taken to a settings screen where he will need to set his email.

I'm having trouble working out what my condition should be here. I'm thinking something like

```
def email_required?
  if user.sign_in_count == 1 && self.authentications.first.provider == "twitter"
    false 
  else
    super
  end
end
```

but (1) the Authentication record is built but not created when this validation is passed, so not available; and (2) I want email to be required immediately after the User is created (i.e., the signin count may still be 1)

Another option may be to check if Twitter params are in the session, something like (pseudocode)

```
def email_required?
  if session["devise.twitter_data"]   
    false
  else
    super
  end
end
```

but accessing the session from a model doesn't seem right.

Would appreciate any suggestions or thoughts, I have a feeling I'm overlooking something obvious!

Comment: You may require an email field value if user chooses a twitter authentification method on the same page. If the are on different pages, you may create a email field with javascript.

Comment: thanks ted. my question is more about ensuring User.create passes validations. email is a required field, but I want all validations to pass when the user signs up with Twitter (without email), but revert to normal such that he can't proceed past the settings page that twitter callback returns to without setting an email